# React Native Error with app lunch witch expo. It can not be debug

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

Thanks for reading!

I have the following app.js:

```
//app.js
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import lightRedColors from '../BaseApp/src/theme/farbe/lightRedColors'

export default function App() {
return (
\<PaperProvider theme={lightRedColors}\>
\<AppNavigator /\>
\</PaperProvider\>
);
}
```

If I remove the  <AppNavigator /> I still have the error.

I have the following error:
`NSRangeException: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

> RCTFatalException
> facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::callSerializableNativeHook(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&)
> facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::callSerializableNativeHook(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&)
> facebook::react::JSIExecutor::nativeCallSyncHook(facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)
> non-virtual thunk to reanimated::ReanimatedHermesRuntime::~ReanimatedHermesRuntime()
> std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>::operator()(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) const
> facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::HFContext::func(void*, hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::NativeArgs)
> hermes::vm::NativeFunction::_nativeCall(hermes::vm::NativeFunction*, hermes::vm::Runtime&)
> hermes::vm::Interpreter::handleCallSlowPath(hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::PinnedHermesValue*)
> hermes::vm::CallResult<hermes::vm::HermesValue, (hermes::vm::detail::CallResultSpecialize)2> hermes::vm::Interpreter::interpretFunction<false, false>(hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::InterpreterState&)
> hermes::vm::Runtime::interpretFunctionImpl(hermes::vm::CodeBlock*)
> hermes::vm::Runtime::runBytecode(std::__1::shared_ptr<hermes::hbc::BCProviderBase>&&, hermes::vm::RuntimeModuleFlags, llvh::StringRef, hermes::vm::Handle<hermes::vm::Environment>, hermes::vm::Handle<hermes::vm::HermesValue>)
> facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::evaluatePreparedJavaScript(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::PreparedJavaScript const> const&)
> facebook::hermes::HermesRuntime::evaluateJavaScriptWithSourceMap(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)
> facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)
> facebook::react::HermesExecutor::HermesExecutor(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Runtime>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::ExecutorDelegate>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::MessageQueueThread>, std::__1::function<void (std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> ()>)> const&, std::__1::function<void (facebook::jsi::Runtime&)>)
> facebook::react::JSIExecutor::loadBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>)
> facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::getDecoratedNativeMethodCallInvoker(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::NativeMethodCallInvoker>) const
> facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::getDecoratedNativeMethodCallInvoker(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::NativeMethodCallInvoker>) const
> facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void ()>)
> 5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
> 5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
> 5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
> CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> RCTConvertArrayValue
> 5623831D-5719-33A9-9691-759F47D714D1
> _pthread_start
> thread_start

I tried to debug but for some reason it does not detect the error(Please see attached image)

So far is I am not getting issues in my app except for this message in my phone...

If you can help me I would really appreciate.

Thanks!!!

I tried to debug with no luck, I asked ChatGPT and Gemini(Bard) with no luck.
I just expecting to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with: `npm audit fix`
It was just a Library issue

Comment: Add the fix that was applied in the answer aswell, the current answer doesn't really state what changed to fix the issue.